# 7zip SFX not extracting files

Tags: vbscript, 7zip, sfx

I'm trying to create a SFX file and run a vbs afterwards.
Here's my config file:

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
InstallPath="c:\\windows\\temp\\"
ExecuteFile="cscript.exe"
ExecuteParameters="c:\\windows\\temp\\script.vbs"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

The .7z archive is not corrupt, I cn=an open and extract files.

here's how I created the .exe:

```
copy /b 7zS.sfx + config.txt + SylinkReplacer.7z SylinkReplacer.exe
```

When I run it a cmd windows flashes I have the feeling it's trying tu run the vbs but I can see it has not been extracted in C:\windows\temp.
I ran process monitor and apparently it extract the files in my users' %appdata% within a temporary folder named 7zNNNNNN which gets deleted afterwards.
Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work (I actually found it on stackoverflow but now I can't find it anymore).

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
ExecuteFile="ReplaceSylink.vbs"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

This is not the best solution since I wanted it to run it with cscript (console) while on many servers the default engine is wscript (GUI).
I'll use something to force cscript like this on this one  http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_engine_force.php